# Wrap exception code

Tags: lua, lua-table

Is there a way to wrap assignment expressions in try/catch blocks.

```
Window = {}
Window.mt = {}
Window.mt.__newindex =function(t,k,v)
         if k=="x" or k=="y" then error("Readonly field", 2) end
         t[k]=v
end
--w is a window 'type'
--try/catch this assignment
w.x = 50
```

thanks
EM

Comment: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.3 and also https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4  the code you posted won't run like that. w is nil and cannot be therefore not be indexed and you did not set Window's metatable anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Lua doesn't have try/catch blocks, but provides [pcall](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-pcall) function that accepts a function as its parameter (along with optional parameters) and catches/reports run-time errors in that function.

So, you may have something like this `if not pcall(function() w.x = 50 end) then ... end` (assuming the error is triggered the way you expect it to be).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out this way:

```
local w = Window.new{height=150, Area=54}     
function setValues(win)                          
  --force an error                               
  win.x = 50                                     
end                                     

local status, err = pcall(setValues, w)
if err then
   print('Error',err)
else
   print('No errors')
end
```